# Custom Map with Directional Routes [NOT Google Maps]

Tags: php, maps

I am trying to create a locational-based map of a specific building. With this in mind, I am aware that I may need beacons to pinpoint locations in the building. I was wondering if it is possible to create this in PHP or any Web Language so certain locations in the building could have a route to go to.

Comment: To map with any degree of accuracy you will need access to GPS. PHP doesn’t have native GPS, however client-side browsers sometimes do.

Comment: It's possible, but not with PHP, and GPS doesn't work well inside buildings. This does seem rather broad to fit well here.